# Capitalization type not working in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I am trying to use capitalization in a textfield in alertcontroller. However I cannot make it work properly. I am using `UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords`. Below you can see how I try to do it.

```
 UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter a Name"
                                                                             message:nil
                                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Title";
        textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;

    }];

    UIAlertAction * cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    UIAlertAction * okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        UITextField *nameField = [alertController.textFields firstObject];
        nameField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    }];

    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:okAction];
```

Comment: Your code works great for me. Each word is automatically capitalized when I enter it. Input:"the birdcage" Output:"The Birdcage". Can you update your question with some sample input text and the expected output?

Comment: I can't see keyboard is capitalized with this code.

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting?  Are you expecting the equivalent of caps-Lock?  That isn’t what it does; it makes the first letter of each word a capital. You would typically use this for a name field where each word is a proper noun.

Comment: Oh, I was expecting keyboard to show upper cases.

Comment: Check [this setting](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/09/18/how-to-keyboard-uppercase-iphone-ipad-ios-9/).